# What operation does Friedberg use in this matrix multiplication proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't understand how Friedberg moves from the vector of summations to $A$ being outside this vector. What rule is he using?

[image]

Comment: that's the definition of multiplying a matrix by a column vector.

Comment: Well, I feel fairly stupid now. Thanks

Comment: don't worry, I had the exact same question when studying from Friedberg... we all have these moments :)