# Understanding calculation of jth column in matrix AB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a theorem found in Friedberg's Linear Algebra which I have trouble understanding.
A is an $m×n$ matrix, B is an $n×p$ matrix, $u_j$ is the jth column of $AB$ and $v_j$ is the jth column of B. 
I am having trouble understanding the proof of $u_j=Av_j$.
$$u_j=\begin{bmatrix} (AB)_{1j} \\ ... \\ (AB)_{mj} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} \sum_{k=1}^n{A_{1k}B_{kj}} \\ ... \\ \sum_{k=1}^n{A_{mk}B_{kj}} \end{bmatrix}$$
Now this is the part where I don't understand. How was is the A factored out? How is this equal to the previous result?
$$=A\begin{bmatrix} B_{1j} \\ ... \\ B_{nj} \end{bmatrix}$$

It further states that the column j of $AB$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ with the coefficients in the linear combination being the entries of column j of $B$. I cannot see this from the above representation however.
Any help explaining this step is appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is similar to another question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729524/what-operation-does-friedberg-use-in-this-matrix-multiplication-proof .  Some discussion in the comments there.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps seeing $u_j$ within the context of the entire matrix multiplication result can help:

$$\underset{m\times n}A\quad \underset{n\times p}B
=\small\begin{bmatrix} 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{1k}B_{k1}} &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{1k}B_{k2}} 
& \cdots &
\color{blue}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{1k}B_{kj}}}
&\cdots &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{1k}B_{kp}} \\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{2k}B_{k1}} & 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{2k}B_{k2}} 
& \cdots &
\color{blue}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{2k}B_{kj}}}
&\cdots &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{2k}B_{kp}} 
\\ && \ddots \\ 
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{(m-1)k}B_{k1}} &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{(m-1)k}B_{k2}}
& \cdots &
\color{blue}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{(m-1)k}B_{kj}}}
&\cdots &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{(m-1)k}B_{kp}}
\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{mk}B_{k1}} &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{mk}B_{k2}}
& \cdots &
\color{blue}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{mk}B_{kj}}}
&\cdots &
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{A_{mk}B_{kp}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Remember that each entry in the matrix multiplication is a dot product.

The expression $\small u_j=\begin{bmatrix} (AB)_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ (AB)_{mj} \end{bmatrix}$ is simply saying "pick all $m$ entries of the column $j$ of the multiplication matrix." This is exactly the result of the $m$ dot products of each of the $m$ rows of $A$ with the $j$ column of $B,$ or $\small A\begin{bmatrix} B_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ B_{nj} \end{bmatrix}.$

> It further states that the column $j$ of $AB$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ with the coefficients in the linear combination being the entries of column $j$ of $B.$

True, because

$$\small A\begin{bmatrix} B_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ B_{nj} \end{bmatrix}
=
B_{1j}\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} \\ \vdots \\ A_{m1} \end{bmatrix}
+
B_{2j}\begin{bmatrix} A_{12} \\ \vdots \\ A_{m2} \end{bmatrix}
+
\dots
+
B_{nj}\begin{bmatrix} A_{1n} \\ \vdots \\ A_{mn}  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much easier to multiply $A$ by $[B]_j$ and see the result, than the other way around!